# Setup Babel/Browserify build for (private) npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, babeljs

I have an npm module `my_lib` that is providing some objects I would like available for use by several downstream modules. `my_lib` is written in ES6, and uses babel to transpile. It lives in a private github repo accessible to the building hosts of the downstream modules. It is important that the downstream modules consuming `my_lib` are able to import symbols from `my_lib` like any other node module.

I would like to be able to write `import { libA, libB } from 'my_lib';` in any of the downstream modules and have `libA` defined as expected by `my_lib`, assuming that downstream module's `package.json` includes in `dependencies` an entry like `"my_lib": "orgname/reponame#branchname"`

I have an entry in `my_lib` `package.json` under `scripts` like so :

```
"postinstall" : "npm run build",
"build": "mkdir ./dist && browserify ./src/index.js -t babelify -t envify -o index.js",`
```

where `./src/index.js` is

```
// Entry point for bundling
export * as libB from "../sublib1/adapter";
export * as libA from "../sublib2/adapter";
```

If necessary, I could call `import {libA, libB}` from `my_lib/dist/bundle`, though this is somewhat undesirable. The main thing is to make all the names I'm exporting from `my_lib` available in the downstream modules. I'm probably confused about what's going on with browserify and babel. I'm perfectly happy to change the postinstall/build hooks to whatever form is more convenient.

Currently, in the downstream package (an `express.js` app), I have the line `import * as adapters from my_lib;` Running  `npm install` on the `express` app completes without error. I see the `index.js` file I expect in `node_modules/my_lib`. When I break in my app after the `import` (or  `require` for that matter), the `adapters` object exists, but none of the  `libB` or `libA` on the object. It seems to be a pure vanilla JS object with no members but `__proto__`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in this case i will just use babel and avoid browserify. I use something like this in `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "babel src/ -d dist/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0"
  }
}
```

Notice that the `main` entry point for the package is pointing to `dist` and not to `src`. This is to make `import my_lib` and `require('my_lib')` (both work well) to use the compiled version of the library.

Additionally this is the content of the `.babelrc` file that it is side by side with `package.json`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use babel and browserify together.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build:js": "watchify assets/src/js/main_1.js -o 'exorcist assets/dist/js/main_1.js.map > assets/dist/js/main_1.js' -d -t [babelify --presets [latest]]",
    "build:scss": "node-sass -w -r assets/src/scss/ -o assets/dist/css/",
    "build": "npm run build:scss & npm run build:js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "exorcist": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  }
}
```

Actual version of package.json: https://gist.github.com/artamonovdev/5f24aaca504e4d1b299bba0413f0a57d